# Using BOTH in English

Tags: grammaticality

What is the difference between " hold the book with both hands" and " hold the book with your hands"?.Also, what is the differnce between " when both you and the person you're talking about" and " when you and the person you're talking about" ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the answer depends on context, since meaning is always context-specific. Putting that consideration to one side, there is a difference in emphasis when "both" is used. In fact, I would say that each sentence refers to an unspoken contrasting situation.

"Hold the book with both hands" emphasises that two hands are to be used. There is perhaps a silent contrast with holding the book with one hand: the meaning is something like "Hold the book with two hands, not just one hand".

"Hold the book with your hands" emphasises a contrast with holding the book with something else. For example, depending on the context, the meaning might be "hold the book with your hands, not your feet". ("Hold the book with your hands" emphasises the importance of using hands for this function, as compared with "Hold the book").

In your second pair of sentences, the meaning could be the same but there is a subtle change of emphasis again. "when both you and the person you're talking about" emphasises that it is the two people who are in consideration - perhaps there is an implied rebuke or comparison in relation to a situation where just one of the two people was taken into consideration.

Comment: What's context-specific?